# How to replace Momentary & Maintained switch with Teensy?

Tags: switches, teensy

I've got a LCD driver board (with some push buttons to open menu/+/-) and a bi-directional HDMI switch (with a latch button to redirect HDMI output to one or another) where I want to remove those buttons and command them via a teensy 2+ I bought. Do I just need to wire board GND and switch GND to teensy and do: (let set PIN_D5 is connected to the lcd board button menu and PIN_D6 to the latch button)

In loop function:

```
pinMode(PIN_D5, OUTPUT); 
digitalWrite(PIN_D5, LOW); 
digitalWrite(PIN_D5, HIGH);
```

to simulate a momentary push

and

```
pinMode(PIN_D6, OUTPUT); 
digitalWrite(PIN_D6, LOW);
```

to simulate a maintained push ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring pin modes should remain in the setup function, as it shouldn't change during the program.

Also, you can keep the button state in a variable and change it later as you simulate a push :

```
bool btnState = false;
// ...
setup(){
      pinMode(PIN_D5, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(PIN_D6, OUTPUT);
    }

void switchButton(){
  btnState = !btnState;
  digitalWrite(PIN_D6, btnState);
}
```

[EDIT]

If you want to simulate a momentary pushed button, you may need to wait a little while between pressing and releasing a given button as below :

```
void pressButton(int button){
  digitalWrite(button, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(button, LOW);
}
```

NB : depending on your LCD driver board logic, you may need to change HIGH level to LOW and vice-versa

Comment: thank you for your answer, pinMode must be in setup you're right. I can then simulate every push button just by using digitalWrite then ?